# Merge .txt files in one .doc, adding file names and page breaks

Tags: bash, file, powershell, text, merge

I have a bunch of .txt files with various names in a folder, and I need to merge them into a single file that can be read in Office Word or LibreOffice Writer.

The tricky part is, the pasted files should be organized by creation date, have a title put before the content and a page break at the end, like this

```
Title of older file
File content
Page break

Title of newer file
File content
Page break
```

I could do this with Java, but it seems a little overkill. It would be nice if this could be done using Windows Powershell, or Unix bash. Added newlines should be Window style, though.

Full disclaimer: I know something about Bash, little about the Powershell and almost nothing about .doc/.odf formats.

Answer (score 1):

Merging TXTs into one DOCX and adding page breaks (PowerShell, requires MS Word):

```
[Ref]$rSaveFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat" -as [Type]
$oWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$oWord.Visible = $false
$sPath = <path to dir with txt files>
$cInFiles = Get-ChildItem $sPath
$sOutFile = $sPath + "\outfile.docx"
$iWordPageBreak = 7
$iNewLineChar = 11
$oDoc = $oWord.Documents.Add()
$oWordSel = $oWord.Selection

foreach ($sInFile in $cInFiles) {
    $sInFileTxt = Get-Content $sInFile

    $oWordSel.TypeText($sInFile)
    $oWordSel.TypeText([Char]$iNewLineChar)
    $oWordSel.TypeText($sInFileTxt)
    $oWordSel.InsertBreak($iWordPageBreak)
}

$oDoc.SaveAs($sOutFile, $rSaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault)
$oDoc.Close()
$oWord.Quit()
$oWord = $null
```

[For explanations see this blog post on TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/22/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-2-0-to-convert-doc-files-to-docx-files.aspx).

Edit: without Word you probably should use ODT format and directly edit content.xml. [Example in Python](http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.ru/2009/03/bash-and-python-scripts-to-unzip-and.html). Though personally I would simply concatenate the TXT files. Unless you have a million of them it's faster and easier to add page breaks manually than actually edit XML.

Comment: I don't have MS Word installed, is it needed to run this? I set `$sPath = "C:\Users\Agostino\Desktop\fld"`, saved this script as a .ps1 file, then opened the PowerShell as Administrator, run the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` and typed the script name to run it. I got a lot of errors and it seems to search even outside of the path I gave it.